# Trying to trigger a SSM:Run Command action when my Cloudwatch alarm enters "ALARM" state

Tags: json, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

Trying to trigger an SSM:Run Command action when my cloudwatch alarm enters the "ALARM" state. I am trying to achieve this with Cloudwatch Rule - Event pattern and by fetching the AWS Cloud Trail API Logs.

Tried with Monitoring and event name as "DescribeAlarms" and stateValue as "ALARM". Just tried adding my SNS topic (instead of SSM:RunCommand) to verify it triggers an email to me when this enters to ALARM state, but no luck.

````
```{
  "source": [
    "aws.monitoring"
  ],
  "detail-type": [
    "AWS API Call via CloudTrail"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "eventSource": [
      "monitoring.amazonaws.com"
    ],
    "eventName": [
      "DescribeAlarms"
    ],
    "requestParameters": {
      "stateValue": [
        "ALARM"
      ]
    }
  }
}```
````

I am expecting when this condition is met, here - any alarm that goes into ALARM state should hit the Target - which is my SNS topic.

> **UPDATE:**

Thanks @John for the clarification. As you suggested, I am trying to go with SNS-> Lambda->SSM Run Command. But I am not able to fetch the instance ID from SNS event. It says [Records - Keyerror]. Read some of your posts and tried all. But not able to get through. Could you please help?

```
Received event: {
"Records": [
{
"EventSource": "aws:sns",
"EventVersion": "1.0",
"EventSubscriptionArn": "arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
"Sns": {
"Type": "Notification",
"MessageId": "********************c",
"TopicArn": "arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:*******************************",
"Subject": "ALARM: \"!!! Critical Alert !!! Disk Space is going to be full in Automation Testing\" in EU (Ireland)",
"Message": "{\"AlarmName\":\"!!! Critical Alert !!! Disk Space is going to be full in Automation Testing\",\"AlarmDescription\":\"Disk Space is going to be full in Automation Testing\",\"AWSAccountId\":\"***********\",\"NewStateValue\":\"ALARM\",\"NewStateReason\":\"Threshold Crossed: 1 out of the last 1 datapoints [**********] was less than or equal to the threshold (70.0) (minimum 1 datapoint for OK -> ALARM transition).\",\"StateChangeTime\":\"******************\",\"Region\":\"EU (Ireland)\",\"OldStateValue\":\"OK\",\"Trigger\":{\"MetricName\":\"disk_used_percent\",\"Namespace\":\"CWAgent\",\"StatisticType\":\"Statistic\",\"Statistic\":\"AVERAGE\",\"Unit\":null,\"Dimensions\":[{\"value\":\"/\",\"name\":\"path\"},{\"value\":\"i-****************\",\"name\":\"InstanceId\"},{\"value\":\"ami-****************\",\"name\":\"ImageId\"},{\"value\":\"t2.micro\",\"name\":\"InstanceType\"},{\"value\":\"xvda1\",\"name\":\"device\"},{\"value\":\"xfs\",\"name\":\"fstype\"}],\"Period\":300,\"EvaluationPeriods\":1,\"ComparisonOperator\":\"LessThanOrEqualToThreshold\",\"Threshold\":70.0,\"TreatMissingData\":\"- TreatMissingData: missing\",\"EvaluateLowSampleCountPercentile\":\"\"}}",
"Timestamp": "2019-06-29T19:23:43.829Z",
"SignatureVersion": "1",
"Signature": "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
"SigningCertUrl": "https://sns.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/XXXXXXXX.pem",
"UnsubscribeUrl": "https://sns.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/?Action=Unsubscribe&SubscriptionArn=arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
"MessageAttributes":
{}

}
}
]
}
```

***Below is my Lambda function:***

```
from __future__ import print_function
import boto3
import json
ssm = boto3.client('ssm')
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')

print('Loading function')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Dump the event to the log, for debugging purposes
    print("Received event: " + json.dumps(event, indent=2))

    message = event['Records']['Sns']['Message']
    msg = json.loads(message)
    InstanceId = msg['InstanceId']['value']
    print ("Instance: %s" % InstanceId)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Able to achieve with below changes:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import boto3
import json
ssm = boto3.client('ssm')
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')

print('Loading function')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Dump the event to the log, for debugging purposes
    print("Received event: " + json.dumps(event, indent=2))
    message = json.loads(event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message'])
    instance_id = message['Trigger']['Dimensions'][1]['value']
    print ("Instance: %s" % instance_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

This probably won't work because **AWS CloudTrail only captures API calls to AWS** and the movement of a CloudWatch alarm into the *ALARM* state is an internal change that is *not* caused by an API call.

I would recommend:

- Amazon CloudWatch alarm triggers an AWS Lambda function
- The Lambda function calls the SSM Run Command (eg [`send_command()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ssm.html#SSM.Client.send_command))

Comment: Just got confused with this - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeAlarms.html. Seems - we can retrieve the alarm through the API call. Am I understanding it in a wrong way? Thanks!

Comment: Your configuration will look for calls to the `DescribeAlarms` API that specifically look for alarms in the _ALARM_ state (eg if you use the management console and go to a page that lists alarms), but it won't do anything when an alarm itself enters the _ALARM_ state.

Comment: Thanks @John. But what will the alarmActions.member would do. Basically what would be outcome of below code -

Comment: ```  {
  "source": [
    "aws.monitoring"
  ],
  "detail-type": [
    "AWS API Call via CloudTrail"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "eventSource": [
      "monitoring.amazonaws.com"
    ],
    "eventName": [
      "DescribeAlarms"
    ],
    "requestParameters": {
      "alarmNames.member.1": [
        "awsec2-i-********************-CPU-Utilization"
      ],
      "stateValue": [
        "ALARM"
      ]
    },
    "responseElements": {
      "metricAlarms.member.1": {
        "alarmActions.member.1": [
          "arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:******:****"``` ] } } }

Comment: Here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/API_MetricAlarm.html - AlarmActions says its the action to be performed once it notices an alarm

Comment: That isn't code. It's a configuration for CloudWatch Events. It says "Tell me when somebody calls the Describe Alarms API call for this specific alarm and for these specific values.

Comment: Cool. Thanks @John